# Combine multiple columns into a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two Excel sheets.

First looks like this

[image]

I have a second sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to map the SOC and ISCO08 codes together in the second sheet, with the multiple ISOC codes for each SOC code going into a single row. However when I go =TRANSPOSE(B2:B4), only the first value (1120) comes up. I would like all three values, separated by a comma, to come up.

Regards

Comment: This problem is at the outer limits of what Excel formulae are built to accomplish - I suspect a formula **could** be written which would do what you're looking for, but the nature of your problem is one that would be far easier to solve with code (vba). A relatively simple **Do... Until** loop could run down the rows of the one sheet and copy across the ISCO08 codes for every match in the BLScodes that it finds.